# How can i toggle classes of a different element using Stimulus in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

i am trying to toggle the class of this element

```
<div data-controller="slider" >
<div data-slider-target="user_slider" class="block">
    <%= render "form", user: @user %>
</div>


</div>
```

on click of this button which is a different element

```
<a  data-action="click->slider#show"> Add user</a>
```

This are different elements and i want them connected to same my stimulus controller.
Stimulus controller looks like this.

```
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["user_slider"]
  close(){
   
      this.user_sliderTarget.classList.remove("block")
      this.user_sliderTarget.classList.add("none")


  }
  show(){
    
    this.user_sliderTarget.classList.remove("none")
    this.user_sliderTarget.classList.add("block")
  }

}
```